# Point shapefile and geotiff in GDAL

Tags: command-line-interface, gis, gdal

I want to add some points that represent coordinates (in shapefile) onto geotiff image which is earth basically. I used command line:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 200 -ts 1000 600 -ot byte -l point point.shp land.tiff
```

but this just gave me a black backgrounded image with red dots.I'm new with gdal and gis so maybe my way could be a little bit wrong.

Comment: Does `land.tiff` exist before running the command?

Comment: yes it is. it is actually a geotiff image which simply shows the earth

Comment: By default it rasterizes only to band 1. If you have an RGB raster, and want to burn the value to all bands add `-b 1 -b 2 -b 3`, that would make it  light grey in your example. The background 'outside' of the points is untouched, but perhaps its not a byte (255) image, therefore showing up as black?

Comment: I'm very sorry for the late answer,i had some health issues. Tried to burn all bands with 255,0,0 values and it did work.Actually i tried this before but the red dots were just one pixel and too hard to see, still work though :) is anyone know how to make bigger these dots or add some symbols to make them more visible?